# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'incorrect syntax near 'table'.'

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get this code working, but every time I debug it, I come across this error.

This is my code:

```
private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);

    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter($"Select Count(*) from Table Where 'Utilizador=' '{textBox1.Text}' and Passe='{textBox2.Text}'", selectConnection: con);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    sda.Fill(dt);

    if (dt.Rows[1][2].ToString() == "1")
    {
        this.Hide();

        Form2 ss = new Form2();
        ss.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Utilizador e/ou Palavra Passe errados. Caso o erro pressista contacte o administrador de sistema.", "SiGiG - Alerta");
    }
}
```

The error is

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'incorrect syntax near 'table'.'

and is thrown on this line of code:

```
sda.Fill(dt);
```

I appreciate all the help I can get, and sorry about my English.

Comment: Are you saying you have a table named "table"? If so, try putting square brackets around it. E.g. [table].

Comment: Table is a reserved keyword for Sql Server. If you really have a table with that name (bad idea) you should write it in your queries with square brakets around it

Comment: Have you tried running this query in an interactive SQL tool like SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: After fixing this trivial error, please pay attention to the fact that your query is vulnerable to [sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work). Use parameters and do not put input typed by your user directly in your query

Comment: Do not “try putting square brackets around it”; `Table` is a bad name for a SQL table, change the name to something meaningful.

Comment: Ok putting the bracklets solved the problem but the same error appears again but now System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ''.'"

Comment: @DavidNogueira another typo, you don't put field names and the = operator between quotes

Comment: And you don't get three columns and two rows out of that query. I really recommend you to read more documentation about SQL and ADO.NET.

Comment: already working, I'm newbie and Steve when he warned me about 3 columns and 2 lines I realized it was another mistake of lack of attention.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an error from SQL engine and is most probably being caused by the table keyword. It is not recommended to use keywords as table names. But if you want to use that, use square brackets as follows:
Select Count(*) from [Table]
You will find related explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26450746/incorrect-syntax-near-the-keyword-table-c-sharp-sql)

You need to remove the single quotes around **Utilizador=** too.

Also, dt.Rows[1 ][2] will return value on the **second row** and **third column**. In your case, you would need: dt.Rows[0][0]

Comment: At least add that he should use ExecuteScalar and explain why.